# Python: Get randomised mode from list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4]
matrix = [[3], [2], [3], [2], [9]]
```

When I use this function to calculate the randomised mode from a normal list it works fine.

```
def get_mode(numbers):
modes = statistics.multimode(numbers)
return random.choice(modes)
```

However I need to get the randomised mode from a list of lists and this function below only returns the last number in matrix even though it is not the mode. How would i solve this issue?

Note: I am only allowed one parameter in the function which is the list of lists

```
def get_mode(numbers):
for item in numbers:
    modes = statistics.multimode(item)
return random.choice(modes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to flatten your list of lists to a single list and then compute the modes. This should work then.

```
def get_mode(numbers):
    #Flatten list
    flatnumbers = [item for sublist in numbers for item in sublist]
    #Compute modes
    modes = statistics.multimode(flatnumbers)
    return random.choice(modes)
```

Comment: In this function, it still returns 9 some of the time, it should only return 2 or 3

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is this what you are looking for?